# What is the recommended approach to collect and send metrics to Prometheus for .Net Core Worker Service?

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-services, prometheus, worker-service

I have a .net core worker service which will run in the background. I would like to capture metrics about the health status of the service and it needs to be consumed by Prometheus.

What is the recommended approach whether we need to use default pull model or pushgateway?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a standalone server of [prometheus-net](https://github.com/prometheus-net/) package which is a great package for working with Prometheus in dotnet, as noted in it's [documentation](https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net#kestrel-stand-alone-server).